# I need to get the contents of a file and redirect the standard output to a variable

Tags: batch-file, redirect, set, echo, pipe

I need to get the contents of a file and redirect the standard output to a variable. I'm making an MTG Deck simulator where you and a bud write your deck in a .txt file in this format:

numberofcards

nameofcard

numberofcards

nameofcard

numberofcards

nameofcard

like that...

If you don't know what MTG is just help me figure out how to get the contents of a file line by line and put it into a variable. Right now I'm using another utility that I call from my program. It echo's the files contents right now, put doesn't put it into a variable. Maybe we could work there and pipe the echo into a set command?

I can't figure this out...

echo %line% | set line%lineccounter%=

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of doing it is

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("file.txt") do set "var=%%x"
```

This will get the first value in the file into the variable. And in each iteration of the for the variable gets overwritten with the content of the next line. To store all the file in memory, we need to simulate an array (no, there are no arrays in batch, but can be simulated)

Define a counter, and for each line in the file, increment the counter and use it to create the name of a variable that simulates an array. Set the value of this variable to the content of the readed file

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "count=0"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("file.txt") do (
    set /a "count+=1"
    set "line[!count!]=%%x"
)
```

For an alternative without the counter, `findstr` can be used to numerate the lines

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=:" %%x in ('findstr /n "^" "file.txt"') do set "line[%%x]=%%y"
```

In this case the line readed comes from findstr output, with the number prefixed in the line and separated by a colon. This colon is used as a delimiter to separate the number from the data and recreate the same structure that in the previous case.